# Replace any 3 letters from the string with random letters

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, random

I want to replace any 3 random letters from the string with random letters from my `letters` variable

```
var str = "HELLO";
var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var arr = str.split('');
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var pos = Math.round(Math.random() * arr.length - 1);
    arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length), 1);
    str = arr.join('');
}
alert(str);
```

I am able to take 3 random letters out right now but can't figure out how to get 3 random letters from `letters` and put them in a random position.

Here is the demo of what I have right now.

http://jsfiddle.net/r1zd7rsw/

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a simpler approach:

```
var str = "HELLO";
var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

var strArray = str.split('');
var lettersArray = letters.split('');

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var pos1 = Math.round(Math.random() * (str.length - 1));
    var pos2 = Math.round(Math.random() * (letters.length - 1));
    strArray[pos1] = lettersArray[pos2];
}

alert(strArray.join(""));
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/r1zd7rsw/7/

Comment: I think you've over-simplified. `String.replace()` will replace the first instance of the selected letter, which may not be the instance you actually meant to replace. That is, it may not be the instance at `pos1`.

Comment: Additionally, this has caused me to realize that neither your solution nor mine guard against replacing the same position more than once. Whoops!

Comment: @SMcCrohan wavv you are right! I updated it, I think it should be working now.

Comment: Your solution is giving me an extra letter at times @erkaner

Comment: @user4756836 did you see the latest code? can you elaborate on extra letter?

Comment: Yes.. i did.. if you go to your fiddle and refresh it a couple times... you will see something it adds an extra letter to `str` for example `HELLO` will become `HELLOR` or something. Ofcourse some of those letters are replaced but there is still an extra letter

Comment: @user4756836 please see the updated link https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/r1zd7rsw/5/ , it was because it was generating an index greater than 4, adding -1 solved it.

Comment: 2 questions why was it generating an index greater than 4? and also, is there a way to retrieve both the letters to be replaced and the letters that replace them from your function?

Comment: @user4756836 because the `random` function was generating a number between 1-5. You can display the letters you mentioned by using these `strArray[pos1]` and `lettersArray[pos2]`

Comment: For some reason, I get a random null sometimes for strArray[pos1] or lettersArray[pos2]. I think it is because you need a check for -1 like the answer below has? Any thoughts?

Comment: @user4756836 finally I think I got it, see the code again, https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/r1zd7rsw/7/

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
var str = "HELLO";
var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var arr = str.split(''),
    //a temp array to store already replaced locations
    temp = [],
    pos, char;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    //since you want 3 different chars to be replaced make sure the current position is not already replaced
    do {
        pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    } while (temp.indexOf(pos) > -1);

    //find the new char, make sure it is not the same as the current character
    do {
        char = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)]
    } while (arr[pos] == char);

    //replace the character at position pos in the array arr, the character to be replaced is randomly selected from teh letters string
    arr[pos] = char;
    //store the current position in the temp array
    temp.push(pos);
}
str = arr.join('');
console.log(str);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ofpmr1Ls/)

Comment: Nice - I overlooked the need to make certain the same position wasn't replaced more than once.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there!

```
var str = "HELLO";
var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var arr = str.split('');
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var pos = Math.round(Math.random() * arr.length - 1);
    var replacementPos = Math.round(Math.random() * letters.length);
    arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length), 1, letters[replacementPos]);
    str = arr.join('');
}
alert(str);
```

All you were lacking was using the same random position selection method against your other string, and then using that position to feed a replacement character into your `slice()` call.

Changing things a bit more from your original, this would be easier to read:

```
var str = "HELLO";
var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

var getPos = function(arr) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
}

var arr = str.split('');
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    arr.splice(getPos(arr), 1, letters[getPos(letters)]);
}
str = arr.join('');
alert(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function randString(num, myStr)
{
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    for( var i=0; i < num; i++ ){
        randChar = possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        repChar = myStr.charAt(Math.round(Math.random() * myStr.length));
        myStr = myStr.replace(repChar, randChar  );  
    }
    return myStr;
}

 alert(randString(3, "12345"))
```

---

DEMO
http://jsfiddle.net/tuga/5h3jf3v0/2/

Comment: Don;t think you understood my question right... check other answers please